# library not found for -lAFNetworking

Tags: xcode, afnetworking, cocoapods

I have a project on Bitbucket that builds fine on one machine.  I cloned it on another machine, did a `pod install`, everything installed fine.  I open the .xcworkspace and it won't build because of the error in the title of this post.

When the project is deleted from the original machine and cloned there (pods installed, etc.) it builds fine.

I don't don't know what's different about the other machine or what information I can provide here to ask this question.

Here's the contents of my podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, "7.0"

link_with 'Extender', 'DefinitiveExtender'

pod 'zipzap', '~> 7.0'
pod 'SQKPieProgressView', '~> 1.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.3'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9'
pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.1'
pod 'HockeySDK', '~> 3.5.7'
pod 'Parse', '~> 1.4'
```

Comment: Going through the same motions, and using your exact `Podfile`, I am able to link against `lAFNetworking`. You probably have not checked-in everything on source machine. There are a number of ways to figure out what's missing, from `diff` to `filemerge`.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue. In my case what was happening was that for some reason libPods wasn't being linked.

Click on the `project`, go to `General`, click on your `target` and then scroll down to `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`. There I made sure to include libPods.a and then the project built fine. Hope that helps.

Comment: where is this libPod.a file located?